# How to implement optional two-way relationships for users?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a user model and these users have some sorts of relationships together.

Example:
John is Jack and Jill's father.

Jack and Jill are siblings.

Jack is friend with Jacob and Joshua.

How can I implement this kind of relationship altogether?
It's a mixture of family relationships and friendships so I'm confused what is the best practice for this?

Comment: you need to make two models : User and Relation

Comment: use this package: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I don't know whether I should use different approaches for friendship and family relations or is there a way to work this out in a cleaner-looking way?

Comment: first, make two models related (one-many relationship) then in your Relation model , you need to have three columns : user_one , user_two , type. there you go.

Comment: You'd need in additional checking for family relation. For example that a person have no 3 fathers (and one of then is a woman), or that two persons are not fathers to each other. The friendship does not need in such checking.

Comment: @AliSafaei what if there were a father with e.g 6 sons. In this case, we're gonna need 7 columns to make it work.
I need to find how many brothers or friends a single user have.

Comment: @sasani72 No. each of his 6 son has a relationship with their father. we will got 6 row in Relation table. take one as an exaple: user_one : the father's user id / user_two : the son user id , type : father_son . you can expand this ... for exaple you can remove "type" column and  add two new column in Relation model : type_one and type_two  . so type_one will be the relation for first user. and type_two will be for second . take the example : user_one : the father's user id / user_two : the son user id , type_one : father / type_two : son.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make two models : User and Relation.
First, make two models related (one-many relationship):

Model:User

```
public function relations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Relation::class);
}
```

Model : Relation

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

then in your Relation model(remember to set it on your Migration also) , you need to have four columns : user_one , user_two , type_one and type_two.

take the example : user_one : the father's user id / user_two : the son's user id , type_one : father / type_two : son .

there you go.